# MVC 4 LabelFor extension combine text and url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.labelfor

I'm trying to build a form in MVC 4 that will have at the end a check box in the following format:

```
       _
      |_| I agree to Terms & Conditions
```

where `Terms` and `Conditions` are actual URLs to the terms and conditions pages.

How I can Implement the `@Html.LabelFor` so that I can insert the two urls? If I understood it right can be achieved with an extension?

EDIT:

Or, I can just change the Display Attribute on my checkbox field to `I agree to` and then in my view use this or `@Html.ActionLink`. Is this a good way?

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AcceptTerms) <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Terms</a> &amp; <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Conditions</a>
```

Comment: I'd just do it manually like your example. When this becomes site-wide with more than a dozen then it becomes worth creating an extension.

Comment: You can see [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) how do create your own HtmlHelper extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go "all in" and create a custom extension to handle your case, but if you're going to use this only in one or couple places, that would be unnecessary.

I'd just enclose the checkbox and the label text "manually" this way:

```
<label>
    @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.AcceptTerms) 
    I agree to 
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
</label>
```